# Hello, I can't install ros indigo on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It shows the follwing. Or is that because it can only be installed on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267575/hello,-i-can%27t-install-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts.-it-shows-the-follwing.-or-is-that-because-it-can-only-be-installed-on-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [Shubhankar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31366/shubhankar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo is only supported on Ubuntu 14.04 . If you want to install ROS on Ubuntu 16.04, I suggest you install Kinetic or Lunar.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shubhankar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31366/shubhankar/) on 2017-07-29**:
Thank you.